# PTIJ: How do people outside of the NY area celebrate Purim correctly?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

One of the ways we mark the joyousness of Purim is by presenting short performances of poetry and song, and from I have read, they all must be produced by [גראַמען](https://grummanstudios.com/)  Studios in Long Island - in fact, they are mostly known by the studio's name!

How does one fulfill this obligation if he is no where near Long Island?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: If I was a New Yorker, I would have probably said something along the lines of: "There's a world outside of New York?!"

Comment: Mods: Question is too Long.

Comment: Hey, it says Mordechai was exiled from [Babylon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon%2C_New_York)

Answer (score 6):

One can also fulfill the obligation if he is within 2000 amos of a Northrop-Grumman facility, or on an aircraft manufactured by the company.

Answer (score 2):

The Gimmel in the beginning of "Gramen" actually stands for its gematria (3) which is short for the tri-state area.

Therefore the rest of the word is actually "Ramen"

So out of towners may eat instant noodle soup while rhyming and singing away!